# how to show the initial array of values after concatenating and sorting

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, dictionary, concatenation

I have 3 arrays of

`a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 11, 46])`, `b = np.array([3, 2, 12, 14, 42])` and `c = np.array([6, 23, 24, 45, 47])`

I have merged these arrays and sorted them in ascending:

`new = np.sort(np.concatenate([a, b, c]))` which results in:

`[ 1  2  3  4  5  6 11 12 14 23 24 42 45 46 47]`

Now I am looking for a way to show from what initial array (a,b,c), each value is picked.
for example, I get `['a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c']`

I am not sure if I am in the right way or should I use dictionaries for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What do you do if there are same numbers in a,b,c** *otherwise*

[image: code]

so if there are same numbers in a,b,c. 'a' will be added to list. if there are same numbers in b,c 'b' will be added to the list.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That worked for this example. however, my real case is very bigger than this. I tested this code, it took very long. I am gonna rewrite my question in a separate post with changes in my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it in less lines but for readability:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 5, 11, 46])
b = np.array([3, 2, 12, 14, 42])
c = np.array([6, 23, 24, 45, 47])
new = np.concatenate([a, b, c])
indices = np.concatenate([np.array(['a']*a.size),np.array(['b']*b.size),np.array(['c']*c.size)])

sorted = indices.sort()
result = indices[new.argsort()]

print(result)
```

This gives the following output:

```
['a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'b' 'c' 'a' 'c']
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. that worked very well. I changed my question that fits better to my real case in a separate post. This code also likes the other ones took very long and I am not sure if there are better ways to do it or not.